# How to kill fastcgi-mono-server4.exe from a rake file?

Tags: ruby, nginx, mono, rake, servicestack

I'm working on automated deployment using Rake of a mono asp.net website to ubuntu server with nginx.

As far as I've discovered fastcgi-mono-server4.exe can't be stopped gracefully and must be terminated. I currently do that manually in htop. How do I do that from rake or the shell?

I've only a few hours of experience with rake & ruby and a few weeks of linux but made a lot of progress already, however somethings are eluding me even potentially obvious ones like this.

Comment: Try `killall -9 fastcgi-mono-server4.exe`

Comment: That helps, I've discovered the exe is really just a glorified script run by mono so I this works: `killall -9 /usr/bin/mono` the .../fastcgi-mono-server4.exe is an argument. And killall doesn't seems to filter based on passed arguments...  Well at least I'm only runing the one Mono app on the server.

Comment: In case if you have more than one similar processes you can find the PID of specific process and stop it by `kill -9 PID`. But this is another story :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the running **mono** process ids in Linux:

```
ps ax | grep mono
```

This will give you something like:

```
user      1452  0.0  0.0   9396   876 pts/4    S+   17:33   0:00 grep mono
user      2810 98.2 16.1 967424 330432 ?       Sl   Mar30 7866:50 /usr/bin/mono /usr/lib/mono/4.0/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe --appconfigdir /etc/init.d/mono-fastcgi /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 /logfile=/var/log/mono/fastcgi.logappconfigdir /etc/init.d/mono-fastcgi /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 /logfile=/var/log/mono/fastcgi.log
```

The **2nd** column contains the process id which you can kill with:

```
sudo kill -9 2810
```

#### Excluding grep from ps output using a character class

Thanks to [@Yevgeniy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1847280/yevgeniy-anfilofyev) comment, you can exclude grep from the ps output by using a grep character class as [explained in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153419/how-does-this-tricky-bracket-expression-in-grep-work), e.g:

```
ps aux | grep [m]ono
```

Which will exclude the grep process from the ps output and give you something like:

```
 2810 ?        Sl   7861:07 /usr/bin/mono /usr/lib/mono/4.0/fastcgi-mono-server4.exe --appconfigdir /etc/init.d/mono-fastcgi /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 /logfile=/var/log/mono/fastcgi.log
```

This now means if you only have one process of mono running you can now kill it with this 1-liner:

```
sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep '[m]ono' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: It's better to run `ps ax | grep m[o]no` to exclude grep string from result.

Comment: Cool, and doing something like this seems to target just the one running on a particular socket `sudo kill -9 $(ps aux | grep bin/mono.*s[o]cket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000 | awk '{print $2}')`